# How the different mathematical topics are related to each other

Tags: soft-question, axioms, foundations

In my actual understanding of maths, each mathematical topic is built from a set of axioms. If two mathematical topics are built from different sets of axioms, how is it sometimes possible to use these two topics to build a theorem. For example, according to Wikipedia, the Pythagorean theorem is an Euclidean geometry theorem. However, the axioms of Euclidean geometry don’t provide any definition nor properties of equalities, so that, in my opinion, the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is not interpretable with only geometry knowledges, so that we have to use algebra to be able to manipulate this expression. Another example is that I remember my calculus professor telling us that one of the theorems he was stating was derived from topology. How the use of multiple mathematical topics based on different axioms to build a theorem can be rigorously justified?

In my searches, I found that ZFC axioms can be used to derive most modern mathematical topics. In which sense this sentence is true? Can modern mathematics be derived from ZFC axioms and from the definitions of the mathematical objects that we are manipulating (lines, equations, functions, numbers, matrices, etc.)? Can most modern mathematics be expressed in ZFC-language?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Some of the questions listed under "Related" on this page may help you.

Comment: Yes, most math can be formulated in ZFC, including Euclidean geometry.  First it must be shown that we can build within ZFC the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, and then we can consider theorems about the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then, if you like, we can show that Euclid's axioms - or your preferred set of axioms for plane geometry - hold for lines in the plane. But they become theorems in this case, not axioms.  Then, anything you can prove from those axioms will also be valid in the ZFC model of the plane.

Comment: Would you care to engage with the comments, sebastien?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is non-responsive.

Answer (score 1):

ZFC is not necessary to answer this question, and indeed may confuse what is an important and elementary question.

Let's ask the question "What is an axiom?".  Historically, the answer was "something whose truth is self-evident as to make it not require proof".  We try to keep these to a minimum, because there is great advantage in *proving* things.  But, ultimately, *all* math and indeed all knowledge is founded on concepts whose clarity is self-evident but cannot be proven (see e.g. "epistemological morass" or [What Achilles Said to The Tortoise by Lewis Carroll](http://www.ditext.com/carroll/tortoise.html)).

If we accept these axioms, we then accept any theorems that can be proven by them.  We can then apply these *anywhere*: to physics, biology, and to other branches of mathematics.

Now, in the past hundred years, a purely formal approach to axioms has developed.  But, this should not be viewed as redefining the notion of axiom to mean "an arbitrary concept which we have no reason to believe is true".  Rather, formalism is a program to formalize a large number of axioms and show how they themselves can be viewed as theorems coming from a much smaller set of "base" axioms.  Yet even formalism needs to start with an ultimate foundation of things accepted as self-evident by logic alone; otherwise, it will be tortoises all the way down.

Comment: 95% of undergrad curriculum is results that came before ZFC was formulated - it's hard to argue that it's still somehow based on ZFC

Comment: No one is trying to argue that math is "based on ZFC", just that it most of it *can be* formulated within ZFC, if you desire.  It's just a convenient framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most math can be formulated in ZFC, including Euclidean geometry. First it must be shown that we can build within ZFC the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, and then we can consider theorems about the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, we can show that the axioms of plane geometry hold in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But they become theorems of ZFC, and no longer axioms. Then, anything you can prove from those axioms will also be valid in the ZFC model of the plane. Thus, there's no need to combine the axioms from the different axiomatic systems - ZFC alone is sufficient. For other kinds of math you may need to add more axioms to ZFC, but for most math, including classical geometry, ZFC is good enough.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for you answer. When you say "ZFC model of the plane", it feels like there is a difference between what we call a plane and the plane defined with ZFC axioms. Can we say that the plane is a specification and that the plane defined with ZFC axioms is the implementation of this specification ? The specification gives the properties while the implementation implements these properties in a particular axiomatic. In that sense, is it possible that the implementation have more properties than necessary/more properties than its specification ?

Comment: That's right. What you call an implementation is called a model. Yes, indeed $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a richer structure than required for Euclidean geometry - in particular it's uncountable, while I believe Euclidean geometry could be modeled with only countably many points.